# How to add horizontal scroll bar for ul table

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have the following code

**HTML Code**

```
<section class="admin-dashboard-manage">
    <ul class="information-header">                                             
        <li>Title</li>
        <li>Start Date</li>                                     
        <li>Start Time</li>
        <li>End Time</li>
        <li>Category Name</li>                                          
        <li>Location</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="information-data-body">
        <ul class="information-data">
            <li>Youth 5.5yr-12yr (Group) </li>
            <li>2015-08-10</li>
            <li>09:30:00</li>
            <li></li>
            <li>Unknown</li>
            <li>Arena Sports @  Issaquah </li>
            <li>Button</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="information-data">
            <li>Youth 5.5yr-12yr (Group) </li>
            <li>2015-08-10</li>
            <li>09:30:00</li>
            <li></li>
            <li>Unknown</li>
            <li>Arena Sports @  Issaquah </li>
            <li>Button</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.admin-dashboard-manage .information-header {
    background: #0aa699 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.admin-dashboard-manage .information-header > li, .admin-dashboard-manage .information-data > li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 24%;
}

.information-data{  
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;      
}
```

What im, trying to achieve is to show all the information columns on one line without the latter columns stacking on top of each other. My problem is when the number of columns increase the columns move down. What I want is to show all columns in one line by using a horizontal scroll bar when the number of columns increase.

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h32x869v/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h32x869v/26/

Answer (score 1):

overflow-x: scroll; 
   white-space:nowrap;

On .information-header.

Comment: with the following you can add the scroll bar but when information is lengthy it goes to the next column.

Comment: How about if you add: 

    'section {
        overflow-x: scrolll;   
    }'

and also do what @Will said with the display:inline on LI's.  And get rid of the overflow I suggested on the header.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline`, rather than `display:inline-block`.

```
.admin-dashboard-manage .information-header > li, .admin-dashboard-manage .information-data > li {
    display: inline;
    ...
}
```

And you can then add appropriate padding, margins, etc. You probably want to ***only*** apply this to your .information-header so you don't "break" the other nice formats you have created.

Edit 1:

I tried to ensure that the text wouldn't jump to the next line with "nowrap" attribute.

```
section  {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: WIth this you can get the horizontal scroll bar but when data is lengthy text moves to the next line. I need to add the scroll bar to the <section> tag

Comment: this is close enough, can u notice the the columns ending half way through : http://jsfiddle.net/h32x869v/10/

Comment: Let me test it out in Google Chrome rather than JSFiddle. One second.

Comment: i don't think this to do with browser, i got the same issue on all browsers earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Answers i got was close enough but the tables ended half way through. This was resolved by adding `display:inline-block;` to head section. And added `width:100%;`for information section.

[updated fix](http://jsfiddle.net/h32x869v/28/)